# CSS creating 3 div blocks in one line, div structure

Tags: css, html

[image]

Maybe anyone could help me with divs structure which would represent image above and if there are any special css parameters of holder div, or other add them too?

Comment: If I understand your needs correctly, you want three divs to vertically divide the page to three equal-width parts?

Comment: exact duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233352/3-divs-middle-centered-sides-zoomable-all-in-one-vertically-centered-div/14233792#14233792, requesting delete for the other post, but please learn to search correctly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The are many ways to do that, one of them is with relative-float

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div style="float:left; width: 50px; height:100px; background-color:red;">Block1
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 50px; height:100px; background-color:blue;">Block2
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 50px; height:100px; background-color:green;">Block3
    </div>
</div>
```

This generates something like

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks, very clear and informative answer with easy solvation. :)

Comment: alex, I used you code and now Im having dificulties adding div under those three, I want to add div with text inside which would go under all of those blocks, but simply adding separate div after your addition showes result not in right place (similating to your blocks), could you help about that?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
```

with CSS:

```
div {
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}
```

?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for html code to get the visual done as shown in your question, this is the place **http://csslayoutgenerator.com/**, where you can generate the html layouts.

Answer (score 2):

[***Working Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/hcQfp/)

CSS:

```
.div {
display:inline-block;
width:150px;
height:400px;
margin:0;
}
#one {
background:green;
}
#two {
background:red;
}
#three {
background:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div" id="one"></div>
<div class="div" id="two"></div>
<div class="div" id="three"></div>
```

You can use CSS `display` property. And Specifying `inline-block`.

Comment: It shows me three blocks but under each other (not next to), maybe its becose those divs are insite container div or body css, which are such: `body {
 background-color:#d6d6a4;
 color: #25670c;
 
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;

 font-family : Times New Roman;
 font-size : 14px;
 text-align: left;

 height: 100%;

}

#konteineris {
 min-height: 100%;

 width: 987px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

* html #konteineris {
 height: 100%;
}` ?

Answer (score 2):

three div :

```
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

with css :

```
div {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

put into these div all content you want.

You can also use float:left instead of display property.

If you want a liquid layout (first and last div have a fixed width and the middle one take all the needed space), you can :

```
.firstDiv {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.lastDiv {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}

.middleDiv {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

you can also use absolute positioning :

```
body {
  position: relative;
}

.firstDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}

.lastDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  right: 200px;
}

.middleDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MPJ72/) JS Fiddle code:

```
<div class="_1">Red</div>
<div class="_2">Green</div>
<div class="_3">Blue</div>

div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
}

._1 {
    background-color:red;
}

._2 {
    background-color:green;
}

._3 {
    background-color:blue;
}
```